# Ambiguous Mockito - 0 Matchers Expected, 1 Recorded (InvalidUseOfMatchersException)

Tags: java, junit, mocking, mockito

i'm facing a very strange problem.

```
 URL = "/my/specific/url/";
 when(this.restHelperMock.post(
 eq(myEnum),
 eq(this.config.apiEndpoint() + URL),
 any(JSONObject.class))).thenReturn(new JSONObject(myDesiredJsonContent));
```

or even with contains

```
 URL = "/my/specific/url/";
 when(this.restHelperMock.post(
 eq(myEnum),
 contains(this.config.apiEndpoint() + URL),
 any(JSONObject.class))).thenReturn(new JSONObject(myDesiredJsonContent));
```

gives me

```
org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.InvalidUseOfMatchersException: 
Invalid use of argument matchers!
0 matchers expected, 1 recorded:

This exception may occur if matchers are combined with raw values:
    //incorrect:
    someMethod(anyObject(), "raw String");
When using matchers, all arguments have to be provided by matchers.
For example:
    //correct:
    someMethod(anyObject(), eq("String by matcher"));

For more info see javadoc for Matchers class.
```

Even if I don't use RAW expressions.
Strangely if I change the contains method to:

```
URL = "/my/specific/url/";
 when(this.restHelperMock.post(
 eq(myEnum),
 contains(URL),
 any(JSONObject.class))).thenReturn(new JSONObject(myDesiredJsonContent));
```

omitting the endpoint, it works.

The Config and RestHelper are both mocked:

```
this.restHelperMock = mock(RESTHelper.class);
this.config = mock(MyConfiguration.class);

when(this.config.apiEndpoint()).thenReturn("http://host:port/api");
```

The URL with ApiEndpoint is equal to what I wanted to mock,
even if it wouldn't be, I should get a NullpointerException, because of false mocking.
But here I don't have any ideea.

Thank you for your answers.

Comment: Is your `contains` and `eq` both from `Mockito`, because even `hamcrest` has both.

Comment: I guess the problem could be that you are calling a mocked method (`this.config.apiEndpoint()`) during the `eq ( ... )` invocation. Try to simple put the complete URL in there ( http://host:port/api/my/specific/url/ ) instead of calling another mock there, which might confuse Mockito, since it relies on internal states for the mocking

Comment: @FlorianSchaetz thank you, that was the solution. I didn't think this could happen. Can you please write an anwser, so I can accept it?

Comment: @FlorianSchaetz Shouldn't the `config.apiEndpoint()` first evaluated, and after passed? So the parameter of `eq(...)` should have nothing to do, if the source object is coming from a mock evaluation , or a simple String literal.

Comment: Honestly, I was just guessing there. The whole problem probably boils down to some complex inherent state of Mockito which prevents this from working. Perhaps someone who is more into Mockito than me can explain that. Will try to debug into it some day to find out otherwise.

Comment: I just happened to face the same issue. Strangely, this works if you try to put a break point and execute.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem seems to be that you are calling a mocked method `this.config.apiEndpoint()` during the `eq ( ... )` invocation. Try to simple put the complete URL in there ( host:port/api/my/specific/url ) instead of calling another mock there, which might confuse Mockito, since it relies on internal states for the mocking.

To be quite honest, I am not that deep into Mockito that I could explain WHY this happens, but I'll probably try to debug into it one day ;-)

Edit: Strangely enough, I seem not to be able to reproduce it with a simpler testcase. There seems to be more here than meets the eye.

Comment: Hmm, I can totally see how this can happen.  From the time the first matcher gets called from the time `when` gets called, you do NOT want to be interacting with any other mocks.  This is because when you use matchers, there's this whole internal stack of matcher calls that gets built up.  Well spotted, Florian.  To fix this, you could place the call to `this.config.apiEndpoint()` on its own line, before the line with `when`.

Comment: The fix is generally pretty simple, if you're passing args that are a matcher and a property of that matcher that you've also spied, just acquire the property in the line above and pass it alongside the thing you got it from.